# Associate a "multi-step system" and an "event system"

Tags: javascript, jquery, parsley.js

I am using Parsley to make a form with several steps/screens like [that](http://parsleyjs.org/doc/examples/multisteps.html) :

If I'm doing only a multi-step form, it works, but I would like to use both (link above) and the [Parsley Events Demo](http://parsleyjs.org/doc/examples/events.html) (because I want to get at least one of the user phone number) at the same time.

How does it work : the user writes his/her personal data at the beginning of the first screen and his/her phone number at the end. He/She validates the first screen and then he can navigate to the second screen if only he/she has provided his/her personal data and, at least, one phone number.

My problem is with the buttons at the end of the screens. In the Multi Steps Form, the button appears as:

```
<html>
    <span class="next btn btn-info pull-right" data-current-block="1" data-next-block="2" />Continuer></span>
</html>
```

In the "Parsley Events Demo", it appears like this:

`<html><input type="submit" class="btn btn-default validate" /></html>`

How can I "associate" these buttons in order to validate the personal data and phone number tests before to the next screen ? If I only use a "submit button" with an "Parsley Event Demo", the system makes a verification about the phone numbers and If I only use a "span button" with a "multi-step form", the system brings me to the second screen. These two buttons behaviors are not compatible.

Thank you.

Comment: What did you try to implement when you tried to make the association?  Then we can see where your logic might be confused and help you untangle it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In parsley they do validation on the next button click.

```
$('.next').on('click', function () { ... }
```

If you need to validate your different case, add a test before next step.

```
if(false === myValidationTest())
 return;
```

And create your javascript validation function for your case.

```
function myValidationTest(){ .... return bool; }
```

Comment: Thanks you Kommu, I used your post to make a validation function for the phone numbers. I call her inside a "if" where I also test if the personal data (block1) are congruent. Inside this validation function, I make my tests and if it doesn't run, I put my message "Fill at least one phone number" like it's written in the Parsley example.

Answer (score 0):

Yo, this is your form fields?

```
<div class="form-group">
        <h4>Correctly fill at least one of these blocks</h4>
        <form id="demo-form" data-parsley-validate>
          <div class="first">
            <label for="firstname">Firstname:</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="firstname" data-parsley-range="[4, 20]" data-parsley-group="block1" />

            <label for="lastname">Lastname:</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="lastname" data-parsley-range="[4, 20]" data-parsley-group="block1" />
          </div>
          <hr></hr>
          <div class="second">
            <label for="fullname">Telephone #1</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="fullname" data-parsley-range="[8, 40]" data-parsley-group="block2" />
          </div>

          <div class="second">
            <label for="fullname">Telephone #2</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="fullname" data-parsley-range="[8, 40]" data-parsley-group="block3" />
          </div>

          <div class="invalid-form-error-message"></div>
          <input type="submit" class="btn btn-default validate" />
        </form>
      </div>
```

Comment: Hello, the problem is that with your code, I wont go to the next screen. It's only make a verification of the data. Thank you.